# How to blur out un-selected items in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I m trying to have a set of status for user to choose inside my flutter app. This is similar to what I want :

[image: The Picture]

But I have no idea how to do it. I tried using a `Row()` of `Buttons()` but **whenever I select one button, the other one will still be a normal button.**

Anyways, I want the selected button to stand out from the rest.

Any help would REALLY be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is the best way but you can do something like this with setState:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  runApp(TestApp());
}

class TestApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TestApp> createState() => _TestAppState();
}

class _TestAppState extends State<TestApp> {
  bool button1Selected = true;
  bool button2Selected = false;
  bool button3Selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    button1Selected = true;
                    button2Selected = false;
                    button3Selected = false;
                  });
                },
                child: Text("away"),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: button1Selected ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    button1Selected = false;
                    button2Selected = true;
                    button3Selected = false;
                  });
                },
                child: Text("At work"),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: button2Selected ? Colors.green : Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    button1Selected = false;
                    button2Selected = false;
                    button3Selected = true;
                  });
                },
                child: Text("gaming"),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: button3Selected ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to keep track of last pressed button in a `StatefulWidget` and use an `Opacity` widget to wrap your buttons. Opacity will be calculated based on the last pressed button, which you can update with `setState`. Initially I assume you want to show all buttons without opacity, but you can adjust in the  code below.

I use an index number for the buttons but there are other possibilities. Also for simplicity I use that same `_onPressed` with a parameter, but of course you can use different ones, only call the `setState` method from each accordingly.

```
class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHome> createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  int? _selectedButtonIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var buttons = [
      Opacity(
          opacity: _selectedButtonIndex == null
              ? 1
              : _selectedButtonIndex == 0
                  ? 1
                  : 0.3,
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _onPressed(0), child: Text('Button1'))),
      Opacity(
          opacity: _selectedButtonIndex == null
              ? 1
              : _selectedButtonIndex == 1
                  ? 1
                  : 0.3,
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _onPressed(1), child: Text('Button2'))),
      Opacity(
          opacity: _selectedButtonIndex == null
              ? 1
              : _selectedButtonIndex == 2
                  ? 1
                  : 0.3,
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _onPressed(2), child: Text('Button3'))),
    ];

    return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly, children: buttons);
  }

  void _onPressed(int buttonIndex) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedButtonIndex = buttonIndex;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use getX to control the state of each button, you can read more about it from the official [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/get)!
you need to check how to use the controller or you can use Obx